# GTK 3 Threads management

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, gtk3

I know that before we needed to use gdk_threads_enter and gdk_threads_leave but now this functions are deprecated and I'm confused about threads.

Should i just add threads with g_idle_add and that's it?

Comment: Be more specific what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

For workers that are unrelated to UI stuff, use the `GThread` API, for anything UI related you *have* to use `g_idle_add`/`g_timeout_add` or attach a custom `GSource` to the desired event loop.
In some cases you'd want to combine those - do some work in a `GThread` and notify the UI from there - as soon as the worker has finished - via `g_idle_add`.

If you are developing a library you could also implement it in a very clean and cancelable manner via the `GAsyncInitableIface` (though that requires a bit more reading before starting to actually implement it).

---

In response to @ptomato's comment:

> You should use gdk_threads_add_idle() and gdk_threads_add_timeout()
>   instead of g_idle_add() and g_timeout_add() since libraries not under
>   your control might be using the deprecated GDK locking mechanism. If
>   you are sure that none of the code in your application and libraries
>   use the deprecated gdk_threads_enter() or gdk_threads_leave() methods,
>   then you can safely use g_idle_add() and g_timeout_add().

Comment: Thanks, I will stick to g_idle_add

Comment: Note that if you want to use GTK in the idle/timeout callbacks, you have to use `gdk_threads_add_idle()`/`gdk_threads_add_timeout()`

Answer (score -1):

Use `g_thread_new (name, func, data)`